# Make React Native ScrollView with snapToAlignement property snappier

Tags: react-native

I made a horizontal ScrollView that has the snapToAlignment property set to "center" so it snaps from card to card when scrolling. But scrolling feels very unsatisfying. It feels like the ScrollView is moving slower than I am swiping. It also often scrolls two pages at a time. I think the problem is caused by the fact that the ScrollView is very small.

Is there a trick to make it more responsive?

Here is the code for the ScrollView:

```
<ScrollView
    horizontal={true}
    decelerationRate={0}
    snapToInterval={150}
    snapToAlignment={"center"}
    showsHorizontalScrollIndicator={false}
>
    {/* ScrollView Content */}
</ScrollView>
```

Here is a video of the ScrollView: https://www.dropbox.com/t/PneQQwv3RYFQHiQU

Thank you for your time ^^

Answer (score 2):

I now found a solution:
you can set the decelerationRate to 0.9 and the disableIntervalMomentum to true and it gives you a snappy responsive scrollView

```
<ScrollView
    horizontal={true}
    decelerationRate={0.9}
    snapToInterval={150}
    snapToAlignment={"center"}
    showsHorizontalScrollIndicator={false}
    disableIntervalMomentum={true}
>
```